# Creating a Twilio Model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, twilio

I am trying to create a twilio model so that I can have attributes such as "type" (welcome, confirmation) and body ("Thank you for signing up!", "You have confirmed").

I believe that creating a model is appropriate because I am using rails Active Admin and I would like to give the admin the ability to change the twilio body for the appropriate message type whenever needed (without having to return to the code).

When I try creating a twilio model:

```
rails g model twilio type:string body:string
```

I get the following error message:

```
The name 'Twilio' is either already used in your application or reserved by Ruby on Rails. Please choose an alternative and run this generator again.
```

How do I access or add to the existing Twilio model to my app files?

I am guessing that this file exists because of the `gem 'twilio-ruby'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Twilio gem is using the same name as model twilio . That is why rails generator not letting you to create twilio model. So it is better to use some other name

Comment: This definitely solves my issue, but I wonder if there is a way to edit the actual twilio model from the Twilio gem.